# User connection to SFTP server using FileZilla refuses to connect

Tags: networking, windows-10, proxy, sftp, filezilla

We have a user on the corporate network who wants to connect to an SFTP server on an external network. He is using Filezilla to initiate the connection. To access this server he must pass through a proxy server and a firewall.

He can only connect to the SFTP server when he is using the corporate WiFi and corporate VPN, but he cannot connect to this server using the network point at his desk. The error log is listed below.

> Status:   Connecting to 104.41.224.191:8922...
>   Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
>   Command:    open "*************@104.41.224.191" 8922
>   Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
>   Error:  Could not connect to server
>   Status: Waiting to retry...
>   Status: Connecting to 104.41.224.191:8922...
>   Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
>   Command:    open "*************@104.41.224.191" 8922
>   Error:  Connection attempt interrupted by user
>   Status: Disconnected from server
>   Status: Connecting to 104.41.224.191:8922...
>   Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
>   Command:    proxy 1 "http://sutm01.woolworths.co.za" 8080 "WOOLWORTHS\W7085385" "*********"
>   Command:    open "*************@104.41.224.191" 8922
>   Error:  ssh_init: Proxy error: Unable to resolve proxy host name
>   Error:  Could not connect to server
>   Status: Waiting to retry...
>   Status: Connecting to 104.41.224.191:8922...
>   Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
>   Command:    proxy 1 "http://sutm01.woolworths.co.za" 8080 "WOOLWORTHS\W7085385" "*********"
>   Command:    open "*************@104.41.224.191" 8922
>   Error:  ssh_init: Proxy error: Unable to resolve proxy host name
>   Error:  Could not connect to server
>   Status: Disconnected from server
>   Status: Connecting to 104.41.224.191:8922...
>   Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
>   Command:    proxy 1 "sutm01.woolworths.co.za" 8080 "WOOLWORTHS\W7085385" "*********"
>   Command:    open "*************@104.41.224.191" 8922
>   Error:  Network error: Software caused connection abort
>   Error:  Could not connect to server
>   Status: Waiting to retry...
>   Status: Connecting to 104.41.224.191:8922...
>   Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
>   Command:    proxy 1 "sutm01.woolworths.co.za" 8080 "WOOLWORTHS\W7085385" "*********"
>   Command:    open "*************@104.41.224.191" 8922
>   Error:  Network error: Software caused connection abort
>   Error:  Could not connect to server
>   Status: Disconnected from server
>   Status: Delaying connection for 5 seconds due to previously failed connection attempt...
>   Status: Connecting to 104.41.224.191:8922...
>   Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
>   Command:    proxy 1 "sutm01.woolworths.co.za" 8080 "WOOLWORTHS\W7085385" "*********"
>   Command:    open "*************@104.41.224.191" 8922
>   Error:  Network error: Software caused connection abort
>   Error:  Could not connect to server
>   Status: Waiting to retry...
>   Error:  Connection attempt interrupted by user
>   Status: Connecting to 104.41.224.191:8922...
>   Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
>   Command:    proxy 1 "10.254.0.10" 8080 "W7085385" "*********"
>   Command:    open "*************@104.41.224.191" 8922
>   Error:  Network error: Software caused connection abort
>   Error:  Could not connect to server
>   Status: Waiting to retry...
>   Status: Connecting to 104.41.224.191:8922...
>   Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
>   Command:    proxy 1 "10.254.0.10" 8080 "W7085385" "*********"
>   Command:    open "*************@104.41.224.191" 8922
>   Error:  Network error: Software caused connection abort
>   Error:  Could not connect to server
>   Status: Disconnected from server
>   Status: Connecting to 104.41.224.191:8922...
>   Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
>   Command:    proxy 3 "10.254.0.10" 8080 "W7085385" "*********"
>   Error:  Unknown proxy type
>   Error:  Could not connect to server
>   Status: Waiting to retry...
>   Error:  Connection attempt interrupted by user
>   Status: Connecting to 104.41.224.191:8922...
>   Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
>   Command:    proxy 1 "10.254.0.10" 8080
>   Command:    open "*************@104.41.224.191" 8922
>   Error:  Network error: Software caused connection abort
>   Error:  Could not connect to server
>   Status: Waiting to retry...
>   Status: Connecting to 104.41.224.191:8922...
>   Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
>   Command:    proxy 1 "10.254.0.10" 8080
>   Command:    open "*************@104.41.224.191" 8922
>   Error:  Network error: Software caused connection abort
>   Error:  Could not connect to server
>   Status: Disconnected from server
>   Status: Connecting to 104.41.224.191:8922...
>   Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
>   Command:    proxy 1 "10.254.0.10" 8080
>   Command:    open "*************@104.41.224.191" 8922
>   Error:  Network error: Software caused connection abort
>   Error:  Could not connect to server
>   Status: Waiting to retry...
>   Status: Connecting to 104.41.224.191:8922...
>   Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
>   Command:    proxy 1 "10.254.0.10" 8080
>   Command:    open "*************@104.41.224.191" 8922
>   Error:  Network error: Software caused connection abort
>   Error:  Could not connect to server
>   Status: Disconnected from server
>   Status: Connecting to 104.41.224.191:8922...
>   Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
>   Command:    proxy 1 "10.254.0.10" 8080 "w7110896" "*********"
>   Command:    open "*************@104.41.224.191" 8922
>   Error:  Network error: Software caused connection abort
>   Error:  Could not connect to server
>   Status: Waiting to retry...
>   Status: Connecting to 104.41.224.191:8922...
>   Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
>   Command:    proxy 1 "10.254.0.10" 8080 "w7110896" "*********"
>   Command:    open "*************@104.41.224.191" 8922
>   Error:  Network error: Software caused connection abort
>   Error:  Could not connect to server
>   Status: Disconnected from server
>   Status: Connecting to 104.41.224.191:8922...
>   Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
>   Command:    proxy 1 "10.254.0.10" 8080 "w7110896@woolworths.co.za" "*********"
>   Command:    open "*************@104.41.224.191" 8922
>   Error:  Network error: Software caused connection abort
>   Error:  Could not connect to server
>   Status: Waiting to retry...
>   Error:  Connection attempt interrupted by user

Why is the connection being refused?

Comment: Issues with corporate IT are off-topic on Super User. Even the solution you present is not universal.

Comment: If I may plead my case, I feel like this post would help people who are having connection issues with SFTP over a network with a proxy and active directory. There is very little coverage of this on the internet.

Comment: I'm not sure where to move this question, but i suppose network engineering would be a better fit?

Comment: There is no Stack Exchange website where this type of question would be on-topic. It’s not like it’ll be removed now. // In your solution, you use a HTTP proxy. It is actually quite unusual that these are set up to allow connections to port 22.

Comment: I forgot to mention all connections to the external network must go through the proxy(UTM in this case), so this solution should work in those kinds of environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Locate the generic proxy setting configuration window,
2. Click the radio button for an HTTP1.1/Connect proxy
3. Enter the proxy socket for the proxy server on the LAN,
4. Enter the user’s proxy authentication username and password.